# Flexport (Deliverr) Website Fast Tag displaying on all products instead of specific ones in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm currently implementing the Flexport (formerly Deliverr) Website Fast Tag on my BigCommerce website, following the official documentation provided by Flexport(https://tags.deliverr.dev/guide/#connecting-product-info-using-data-skus). The goal is to display the Fast Tag badge only on products that have Fast Tag enabled through Flexport. However, I'm facing an issue where the Fast Tag badge is displayed on all products, regardless of whether they have the Fast Tag or not.

Here is the implementation I've used in my product card component:

```
<deliverr-tag data-skus='["{{this.sku}}"]' data-sellerid="somesellerId"></deliverr-tag>
```

I have verified that the SKU passed in the data-skus attribute matches the SKU of the specific product. However, the badge still shows up on all products.

I've double-checked the Flexport documentation, but I'm unable to identify what might be causing this issue. Can anyone please provide guidance or solutions to ensure that the Fast Tag badge displays only on products that have the Fast Tag enabled from Flexport?

Thank you for being so helpful!